# How to make Vim open in a terminal instead of XQuartz when logged onto a remote server?

Tags: vim, ssh, remote-access, xquartz

When I'm on my own computer's terminal, when I enter the command `vim filename` and vim opens the file in the terminal.

When I log into my school account using SSH, and I enter `vim filename`, nothing happens.
I assume it's trying to open it using XQuartz, which I recently uninstalled.

How do I make it open in the terminal window, like on my own computer?

I have tried not using `-Y` when logging on, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens? Do you get an error? Are you sure vim is installed on the computer you are try to connect to using ssh? Can you try `vi filename`, `which vim`? vim is a terminal application it it doesn't need X session.

Comment: @stee1rat Nothing happens, no error. I can't enter any more commands in. vi filename does the same thing.

Comment: Do you use `-X` besides `-Y`? Try adding `-x` to `ssh` command line to forcefully disable X11 forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a workaround. You can try to edit it using the `scp` option in Vim.

Just run `vim scp://user@schoolserver.edu/path/to/your/file` from your terminal and you'll start editing the file using Vim from your local machine.

If you want to learn more about `scp` in Vim type `:help scp` in Vim.